# Is there any API to return ERC20 tokens?

Tags: tokens, etherscan

I'm using Etherscan.io pro API, but there is a problem!
No Icon provided in the result.

this API for getting token list by wallet address:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=addresstokenbalance&address=0x7cD6232194d40081021359383a19c6e4D5a8bB01&page=1&offset=100&apikey=YourAPIKey
```

and this is response:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "OK",
    "result": [
        {
            "TokenAddress": "0x1d4ccc31dab6ea20f461d329a0562c1c58412515",
            "TokenName": "Talao",
            "TokenSymbol": "TALAO",
            "TokenQuantity": "50000100000000000000",
            "TokenDivisor": "18"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need token icon in response also.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use those three api :

https://docs.chainbase.com/reference/getaccounttokens

https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-gettokenbalances

https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-the-native-balance-of-a-smart-contract-vault

you can also modify the address indside their pages.